# why does the following code crash. (dynamic memory)?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

My program counts the occurrence of each digit from 0 to 9 in a string. It seems to me that i have done everything correctly, but a problem still persists.

```
int main(){
    string word = "23456745";
    int* ReturnArray = count(word);

    for(int i =0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << i << ": " <<  ReturnArray[i] << " \n";
    }

    delete [] ReturnArray;

    return 0;
}

int* count(const string& s){
    int length = s.length();
    int* array = new int(10);
    int counter =0;

    for(int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
            char character = s[i];
            int value = static_cast<int>(character -'0');
            if(value == j)
                counter++;
        }
        array[j] = counter;
        counter = 0;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: did you debug it? where does it crash?

Comment: A small point. Since you know the exact size of the array, 10, why dynamically allocate it? Declare `int array[10]` in main() and change count to `void count(const string& s, int* array)` and call it `count(word, array);`

Comment: Also you don't need loop over the string multiple times to count the digits. You can do a single pass and simply increment the correct bucket based on which digit is observed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int* array = new int(10);
```

This creates one int with value 10... for 10 ints you want `[10]` not `(10)`.  Then I suggest you put in...

```
std::cerr << "j " << j << '\n';  // add some trace
array[j] = counter;
```

...and learn to debug.

When you've got it working, rewrite it to use `std::vector` - it's a much safer and more powerful approach.